# Jenkins Workflow: How to execute integration tests in parallel

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Hi all i have been working on tis issue for some time and i cant find solution becouse integration tests run each time in new directory called MyProject@1,2,3,4...

I have stated that i want them to run in specific directory but that is not helping. Here is example of my code.

```
parallel( FirstSuite: {
    node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 0 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=FirstSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/FirstSuite'
         } 
     }
 }, 
 SecondSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 20 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=SecondSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/SecondSuite'
         }
     }
 },
 ThirdSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 40 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=ThirdSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/ThirdSuite' 
         }
     }
 },
 FourthSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 60 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=FourthSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/FourthSuite' 
         }
     }
 },
 FifthSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 80 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=FifthSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/FifthSuite' 
         }
     }
 },
 SextSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 100 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=SextSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/SextSuite' 
         }
     }
 },
 SeventhSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 120 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=SeventhSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/SeventhSuite' 
         }
     }
 },
 EighthSuite: {
     node('master') {
         ws('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
             sh 'sleep 140 && mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev  -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=EighthSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/log/EighthSuite' 
         }
     }
 },)
```

But i am still getting errors in maven that pom is not readable, and that directory is missing becouse this ws command is not helping. My integration tests are executed in MyProject@2, @3, @4 and so on...

```
[FirstSuite] + mvn -s settings.xml -f java/pom.xml integration-test -P dev -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository -Dit.test=FirstSuite -Djava.io.tmpdir=java/target -Dlog.dir=java/target/FirstSuite
[FirstSuite] Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
[FirstSuite] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[PmClientTestsuite] [ERROR]   
[FirstSuite] [ERROR]   The project  (/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject@16/java/pom.xml) has 1 error
[FirstSuite] [ERROR]     Non-readable POM /opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject@16/java/pom.xml: /opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject@16/java/pom.xml (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] 
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] 
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[FirstSuite] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use **ws** step. Instead of it use **dir** which does not check uniqueness of the path.

From the Jenkins Pipeline Snippet Generator help hint about **ws**:

> If concurrent builds ask for the same workspace, a directory with a suffix such as @2 may be locked instead. Currently there is no option to wait to lock the exact directory requested; if you need to enforce that behavior, you can either fail (error) when pwd indicates that you got a different directory, or you may enforce serial execution of this part of the build by some other means such as stage name: '…', concurrency: 1.
>
> If you do not care about locking, just use the dir step to change current directory.

In addition I would suggest moving **node** out of **parallel** if your actual intention is to perform all execution streams on the same node. Like this:

```
node('master') {
    dir('/opt/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject') {
        parallel FirstSuite: { ... },
                 SecondSuite: { ... },
                 <... other suites ... >
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy and very helpful, you just saved my day. Not sure y but my project wont run correctly in the 2nd workspace. Not even with the local maven repository located in the workspace.